# TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'I.setDebugLogsEnabled')

Tags: android, react-native, revenuecat

We're using RevenueCat SDK on our RN app. It's published only for Android. Something causing crash on app that in production. This error occurs in a certain part of the users, not all.

RN: 0.63.4

react-native-purchases: 4.0.0

There is a crash report in below:

```
com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'I.setDebugLogsEnabled')

This error is located at:
    in N
    in c
    in Unknown
    in A
    in RCTView
    in View
    in RCTView
    in View
    in C, stack:
setDebugLogsEnabled@1227:4414
<unknown>@406:1500
mi@93:60183
Dl@93:78547
unstable_runWithPriority@202:3882
<unknown>@93:78167
G@202:2821
n@202:194
y@131:580
callTimers@131:2629
value@27:3350
<unknown>@27:747
value@27:2610
value@27:719
value@-1

at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportException(Unknown Source
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke (JavaMethodWrapper.java:149)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke (JavaModuleWrapper.java:21)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run (NativeRunnable.java)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:883)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:100)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage (MessageQueueThreadHandler.java)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:237)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run (MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:37)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:919)
```

Thanks for your help.